# Editing yml file has no effect

Tags: php, symfony1

Sorry if the question sounds stupid, but I'm not too experienced with PHP but I must style some parts of this [abandoned open source app](http://siwapp.org) built on Symfony and Twig.

So I have `template.yml` and its the ONLY place where these invoice templates are, I did a grep search to confirm. File contents looks like so:

```
Template:
  Template_1:
    name: Invoice Template
    slug: invoice-template
    models: Invoice
    template:
       ....
```

Its HTML and CSS which when I edit has no effect on the app. I tried disabling the cache in `settings.yml`:

```
prod:
  .settings:
    no_script_name:         true
    logging_enabled:        true
    error_reporting:        <?php echo ((E_ALL | E_STRICT) ^ E_NOTICE)."\n" ?>
    web_debug:              true
    cache:                  false
```

and I also did:

`./symfony cache:clear`

... but no luck. What am I doing wrong here? And yes I checked the path several times, its not that I'm editing the wrong or local file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking at [fixture](http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/gentle-introduction/1_4/en/16-Application-Management-Tools#chapter_16_populating_a_database) file. It is loaded during installation, quite possibly only as optional step to load demo data. And it's loaded into database, so that's where you need to look, table `template`, column `template`.

Comment: Template file in DB? No doubt its a crappy piece of software, but unfortunately its perfect for my requirement. :(

Comment: Depends on the requirements. In this application, invoice template is data, so they put it to database. As it's twig, it might be cached as php on filesystem, I don't know.